# SQL Seleccionar valor random de un conjunto de 4 números

Tags: sql-server

Hola comunidad agradezco de antemano esta respuesta, necesito hacer un select aleatorio entre estos 4 números (Valores siguientes "1 o 15 o 30 o 60") Existe algún select en SQL server como este **pero que no sea del 1 al 99** si no de cualquiera de los tres 1 o 15 o 30 o 60

el ejemplo que tengo es:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(99-1)+1
```

Answer (score 1):

La idea: Generar un índice aleatorio y un switch case

```
---- Creamos las variables
DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT

--Esto va a crear un número random entre 1 y 4.
SET @Lower = 1 ---- el mínimo número random 
SET @Upper = 4 ---- el máximo número random
SET @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)

--Con esto tenemos un número de ese conjunto: 1-15-30-60.

SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN @Random = 1 THEN "Al azar es 1"
    WHEN @Random = 2 THEN "Al azar es 15"
    WHEN @Random = 3 THEN "Al azar es 30"
    WHEN @Random = 4 THEN "Al azar es 60"
END AS 'Numero Aleatorio'
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta más sencilla es ordenando por un valor aleatorio cuya forma más fácil de obtener es por medio de `NEWID()`. `RAND()` no genera valores realmente aleatorios.

```
   SELECT TOP (1) n --Tomamos sólo un valor
   FROM (VALUES(1),(15),(30),(60))x(n) --Creamos una tabla al vuelo con los 4 valores
   ORDER BY NEWID(); --ordenamos los valores de forma aleatoria
```